# Internet Explorer/MS Edge set-cookie works for 127.0.0.1, but won't work for localhost

Tags: internet-explorer, session, cookies, session-cookies

Using Chrome or Firefox, the set-cookie works correctly for both localhost and 127.0.0.1. However, IE and MS Edge both ignore the set-cookie for localhost, but accept the 127.0.0.1 cookie.

Works: http://127.0.0.1

```
Set-Cookie: user_auth=16c66667dd3a04018d7c59d30eb5bfd928031e5cc67d889a2332d85b0f4c2e8b68bdc1a2cc2e5590e40a9c606827b20af72219f562d3a1d747b272fed9876eb1fb0808b99c9eab71430ee408a36ec810f2182819a5ce09972866f18f2b1f03a3b42fe585cdd837dc122e23bb90ecf8ac94471fc5097a7fb28b83c615149a9aca; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Sat, 30 Jul 2016 16:14:26 GMT; Path=/; Domain=127.0.0.1; HTTPOnly
```

Doesn't Work: http://localhost

```
Set-Cookie: user_auth=cdbdfa9bedf0536d7db57593779ead321e949216dedba5c79d124b56860c0779a4d9942dc4da9aa51da59d186624fae6932fcd891da927f7ffff283b86660ac1dd6666066ff269393c47ec301011557ccd90a797336b4ccc8c508c55c9d17332f033cdd84e564072b73366ed764a0346ea044815a0f112e9d169939831e69a25; Max-Age=31536000; Expires=Sat, 30 Jul 2016 16:20:48 GMT; Path=/; Domain=localhost; HTTPOnly
```

Both have a P3P policy set, even though it's not needed:

```
P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"
```

Thanks in advance, I'm totally stuck.

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Likewise. Is this a bug in IE/Edge? Or a setting somewhere in Windows?

Comment: This is a question about commercial software and not directly related to programming. Should be closed.